# Does functional programming use object data structures?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, prototype

I have been doing a lot of research on functional programming and I am really liking the idea of thinking of code as functions. The thing that I am not really gasping, and can't seem to get a clear answer to without directly asking are:

- does functional programming use objects?
- does it like prototypal inheritance?

If it doesn't, then how do you structure your data?

An example might be like:

```
let dragons = { 
    name : "default",
    age : 0,
    element : "fire"
}
let fireDragonJoe = Object.create(dragons);
fireDragonJoe.name = "Joe";
fireDragonJoe.age = 3009;
```

Maybe I am just overthinking all this and the answer is just super simple. If anyone knows of a good reference material that actually teaches the why and how of functional programming, preferably for Javascript that would be great.

Comment: When formatting code, for large blocks use four spaces.  For single line snippets, enclose the code in backticks.  Don't mix the two for the same block of code.

Comment: `dragon` !== `dragons`

Comment: If you want to really learn functional programming, pick up a functional language such as Scheme, LISP or Haskell.  Functional programming does not mean "uses functions"

Comment: Yes, you can use objects with functional programming. Redux is an example of a JavaScript library which does so.

Comment: funny thing, `Object.keys(fireDragonJoe)` returns the keys without `element`.

Comment: @Amy I tried indenting using 4 spaces but the preview of it didn't look like it was going to show it as code.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks, I fixed it. I was writing in a hurry and dealing with my 3 year old.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo What structure would you suggest. I will have a bunch of the same type of object, Dragon in this example and they will all have the same attributes.

Comment: scala is an example of a language that is both OOP and functional and the two paradigms coexist.

Comment: A Mostly Adequate Guide to Functional Programming is a good place to start with FP in JavaScript.  https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Many functional programming languages make use of objects.

A few examples:

- The [Racket Programming Language](https://racket-lang.org/), a descendant of Scheme, [supports objects, classes and inheritance](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mzlib_class.html).
- [Clojure](https://clojure.org), a LISP that runs on top of the Java Virtual Machine, can make [use of objects](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop).
- [F#](http://fsharp.org), a descendant of ML, runs on top of .net framework, and can also [use objects](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/classes/).
- [OCaml](https://ocaml.org), another descendant of ML, [makes use of objects](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/objectexamples.html).
- [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org), is a powerful combination of [object-orientation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html) and [functional programming](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html) features.
- Etc, etc.

The point being that object-orientation and functional orientation are not mutually exclusive concepts.

In these days, more and more object-oriented languages incorporate functional programming concepts. For example, [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) and [Java](http://www.lambdafaq.org/) have support for functional types on top of their first class support for objects.

As such, I would say that there is nothing about prototypal inheritance that precludes a language from supporting functional programming features and vice versa.

Now, objects are not the only data structure that you can use. There are languages in which there are no concept of objects as in object-oriented programming and so you use other mechanisms to define complex types and data structures.

For example, in SML you can define [tuples, records](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/recitations/rec02.html), or other forms of [abstract data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type). Haskell supports all these and more e.g. [algebraic data types and type classes](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses). Clojure supports a range of [other data types](https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes) like records, protocols, etc. Most functional languages have powerful support for lists, maps and other fundamental collections and composite data types.

So there's a plethora of other options out there. You just have to go out and play with a few other languages that are not object-oriented to find them out.

**Functional Programming Resources**

There are simply too many resources out there to learn functional programming. I can certainly recommend you a few of my favorites, but I'm pretty sure anyone would tell you something entirely different. You will have to start experimenting in order to find your own path.

These are some resources I have used myself in the past to learn FP.

- [Functional JavaScript](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028857.do): a great book that could help you a lot since you're already working with JavaScript. Its chapter 9: "Discover how to code without using classes", seems to be what you're looking for.
- [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com): in my case, when I started with functional programming I preferred to use a language that would not let me use object-oriented features,  I wanted to use a language that would force me to think in a functional way, that's why I started with a bit of Haskell and this awesome book.
- [Programming Languages](https://www.coursera.org/learn/programming-languages): a magnificent course in Coursera. When I took it, it was a single semester course, but they have divided it in multiple courses these days. The course covers fundamental functional programming concepts in SML and Racket and Ruby. So a perfect combination for what you want to achieve: learn the differences between FP and OO.
- [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1): also a great course from Coursera.
- [Introduction to Functional Programming](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-functional-programming-delftx-fp101x-0) a course from edx.org that covers fundamentals of FP using Haskell.
- [Functional Programming in C#](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-c-sharp) one of the best books I found out there.

Comment: One might argue that Clojure's protocols are the purest form of OOP, nothing wrong with calling record instances "objects" :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I am stuck using javascript, HTML, or excel visual basic. I am working on a project that I can install any new software. So I guess prototypes are the way to go?

Comment: @JustinGagnon even if you're stuck with JavaScript, you have plenty of options, for example you create your programs in [Elm](http://elm-lang.org) and transpile them to JavaScript. These days you have even other options, e.g. [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org). Under the hood even these will probably use whatever JavaScript offers today to provide their functional programming features. As I said in my answer, I don't see where you see a conflict between prototypes and functional programming. Honestly, I still don't get that part of your question so I'm not sure I can't help you on that one.

Comment: @JustinGagnon Prototypes on their own are not a solution to anything. They are not "the way to go", they're just a useful tool that you can apply when it fits. In fact JS has pretty powerful OOP through duck-typing and dynamic method dispatch even without any prototypical inheritance.

Comment: I guess my question is/was since prototypes and their inheritance are mutable doesn't that go against the idea of immutablilty of functional programming. If that makes sense. I am still very new to the concept of FP so I'm trying to figure it all out.

Comment: @JustinGagnon, if you define your data structures, why couldn't you make them immutable yourself? You may also consider using libraries that enforce the functional features you want to use, e.g. [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Comment: Never heard of immutable.js. I'll look into it. I guess in around about way you answered my question. Do you know of any good resources that will teach functional programming?

Comment: @JustinGagnon The prototype chain should never be mutated. Also you usually don't mutate your prototype objects after having them set up initially. That objects are mutable might be the default, but you can always a) choose yourself not to mutate them b) force immutability with [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Comment: @JustinGagnon, I have shared some interesting resources that you may consider, but as I said, it is hard to recommend because there are plenty of good material out there. You have to start experimenting and hacking some code to learn and gradually become more and more proficient on the topics.

Answer (score 3):

OOP and FP are tools for making abstraction on problem solving.
They are Independant. Programming language is like a tool box.
You can use both tools in hybrid languages like ocaml and others, they don’t require one another, it’s up to you.

The principles used behind the conception of both tools are Von Neumann architecture for imperative and OOP, and lambda calculus for FP.

There is a link between your algorithm and your data structures . OOP manage states, due to the von Neumann roots. States are handled through mutability, and use for example loops. In FP, loops and assignments operator doesn’t exists. In FP you use recursive data structure heavily, and use recursion functions for exploring this data structure.

That’s why OOP is a great tool for matrix, because of mutability need, and FP is great for Tree.

Data structure will guide your choice of abstraction tool. You mix the tools, but you generally prefer to use the right tool for the right data structure, in order to avoid heavy code and performance issues.

Comment: what do you mean that FP is great for Tree? When inserting a new leaf node into a huge tree, we'll have to do a lot of rotations which will mutate the tree, i'm not sure i follow this one sentence "That’s why OOP is a great tool for matrix, because of mutability need, and FP is great for Tree."

Comment: @Aranha tree is defined recursively. So recursivity is the natural approach to implement tree algorithms. FP language implement recursivity appropriately in order to doesn't have stack overflow. So for all kind of recursive datastructure FP is great.