# code smell sonar Replace this lambda with a method reference

Tags: java, lambda, sonarqube, method-reference

Sonar is throwing code smell at the below lines:

```
File file = new File(xxxxxx);
Arrays.stream(file.listFiles()).map(path->path.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();
```

I already converted using Steam, but it still shows code smell and asks for method reference.

How can I rewrite the above code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to understand method reference in Java 8 (assigning class method to functional interface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64339742/trying-to-understand-method-reference-in-java-8-assigning-class-method-to-funct)

Comment: I tried to change Collectors::toList and file::listFiles . but got exception

Comment: Because you need to change the lambda function to method reference, `Collectors.toList()` and `file.listFiles()` are not lambdas, those are just normal method calls.

Comment: sonarqube is definitely wrong, the code actually smells due to `java.io.File#listFiles()`

Comment: Couldn’t that code be replaced with Arrays.asList([file.list()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#list()))?  (A word of caution:  both file.list() and file.listFiles() will return null if there is any error, including the case where the directory does not exist.  Consider using Files.newDirectoryStream or Files.list instead, both of which throw an exception instead of returning null.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts are wrong because the lambda function is the one with the `->` operator, so the correct change is:

```
Arrays.stream(file.listFiles()).map(File::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();
```

Comment: Or better: `Arrays.stream(file.listFiles()).map(File::getName) .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[ ", " ]"))` to create the intended string in the first place instead of going the `List` detour.