# Can we pass objects to function parameters in functional programming?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have been mostly writing Object-oriented code in my day to day work and have little experience with functional programming.

In JavaScript/typescript code, we can definitely pass objects as parameters to functions. My question is whether passing objects to functions violates the functional programming paradigm as I am mixing object oriented code with functional style programming. (Even though The object passed into the function does not get mutated).

For example, if I have a function `f(x,y) => z` where `x` is an object that defines some interface. Object `x` makes a network call to access some resource which is used to compute `z`. We can say that such a function still adheres to the functional programming concept of it having no side effects and it being pure even though there is mixing of OO code in the function parameter ?

Hope my question was clear.

Comment: I wonder if this question is related: [Does functional programming use object data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821789/does-functional-programming-use-object-data-structures)

Comment: Yes. Yes we can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I have a function `f(x,y) => z` where `x` is an object that defines some interface. Object `x` makes a network call to access some resource which is used to compute `z`.

If `x` makes a network call and uses the result to compute `z`, then it's (by most definitions) non-deterministic (since it performs I/O) and thereby not a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). This further means that `f` is impure, too. [I don't consider that FP](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/11/19/functional-architecture-a-definition). Rather, it's [an attempt at Dependency Injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/dependency-injection-is-passing-an-argument).

This doesn't mean, however, that you can't pass 'data structures' as parameters - they just have to be immutable or other pure functions.

If, instead, object `x` implemented an interface that defines a pure function (an algorithm, say), you can pass it as a parameter, use the pure function, and the function that uses the 'object' might still be pure.